# why gh-unit is better than SenTestCase ( in Xcode4 )?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4, ios4, gh-unit

This post ["Unit Testing in Xcode 4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388370/unit-testing-in-xcode-4) talks about unit test, let me know the best solution ["gh unit"](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) , but I know that xcode4 just provides SenTestCase , so question here to know more reasons why you choose gh-unit ? And now xcode4 provide native unit testing framework, do you think that is the best choice now?

Answer (score 4):

The best answer is "...well it depends."

Here is a *very* good post on what the determining factors are (as well a a good comparison between the two):
http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/04/15/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-use-ocunit-and-sentest-instead-of-ghunit/